# How to select a single input value among multiple inputs?

Tags: jquery

I have a number of inputs with an select button for each to allow the user to select a coupon code.

This is what I have, which has the desired result:

```
<!-- code 1 -->
<input id="code1" type="text" value="codeval1" disabled />
<button id="btn1">Select</button>
<br>
<!-- code 2 -->
<input id="code2" type="text" value="codeval2" disabled />
<button id="btn2">Select</button>

<input id="text" value="" type="text"></input>
<button id="clear" >clear selection</button>
```

And the script:

```
$("#clear").on("click", function() {
       var text = $('#text');
       text.val("");
});

$('#btn1').on('click', function(){
    var text = $('#text');
    var code = $('#code1');
    text.val(code.val());
});

$('#btn2').on('click', function(){
    var text = $('#text');
    var code = $('#code2');
    text.val(code.val());
});
```

Is there an easier way of doing this without having to re-write the function for every input/button ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do everything with a single (anonymous) function, as demonstrated below:

```js
$("body").on("click","button",function() {
   with ($(this))
     $('#text').val(hasClass('sel')? prev('input').val():'')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- code 1 -->
<input id="code1" type="text" value="codeval1" disabled />
<button class="sel">Select</button>
<br>
<!-- code 2 -->
<input id="code2" type="text" value="codeval2" disabled />
<button class="sel">Select</button>

<input id="text" value="" type="text"></input>
<button class="clear" >clear selection</button>
```

I simply test, whether the class `sel` exists for the clicked button (`$(this)`) and then copy the value of the previous input field to the target. Otherwise I place an empty string into the target. My event binding is done on the `<body>` of your page so potentially all buttons will have this functionality. In a real example you would restrict the scope to a container (`<div>` or `<form>`) in which all buttons will have this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution

```js
$('.sel').on('click', function(){
    var value= $(this).prev('input').val();
    $('#text').val(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- code 1 -->
<input id="code1" type="text" value="codeval1" disabled />
<button class="sel">Select</button>
<br>
<!-- code 2 -->
<input id="code2" type="text" value="codeval2" disabled />
<button class="sel">Select</button>

<input id="text" value="" type="text"></input>
<button class="clear" >clear selection</button>
```